# Image texture material goes to scale up and shiny

Tags: transforms

I am a newbie to use Blender 4.0.2, starting to try paint a surface with 'sand-texture' which downloaded from ambientcg.com. The resolution for image is 1024x1024x24. I do not need very detail of sand surface.
Image I use is Color, Roughness and NormalGL into Principled BSDF.
In Blender-preview, it looks good as what I want.
But after export to FBX, I got the grain of sand goto huge (basketball size), too shiny and too dark than original look.

I do not know how to fix 3 problems above.
Could someone give the solution ?

Comment: I think you'll have to show us your shader-tree, so we can see what space you mapped your texture into while painting. Better yet, pack your texture into a representative .blend file, and share on  https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem in Blender or if you have to fix the texturing in whatever software you open the FBX file with...?

Comment: Ups, sorry for forget to provide file in blender, image texture I use and final result of FBX. Here's the link...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ngWXdBxkeTYq0CIXJWjOEIYy_jkjfuOH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @Robin... Here's the file ...
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Ok45ykqB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ok45ykqB/)

Comment: What's the problem of my blend file ?